# How do I assign text to the "void PrintIntro" function?

Tags: c++

So far I have typed this,

```
#include iostream

using namespace std;

void PrintIntro();
```

I want to assign a actual text now to the PrintIntro function so that in my main program I can just type 
PrintIntro() and when the program runs the text assign to the function will show.

So far I have tried this after "void PrintIntro();"

```
    { /*PrintIntro*/
    cout <<
         "==================================================" << endl;
    cout <<
        "Welcome to the Math Practice Program!!!!!" << endl;
    cout <<
        "This Program will help you practice elementary math" << endl;
    cout <<
        "==================================================" << endl;
    /*PrintIntro*/

}
```

But then I get the error under the "{" symbol indicating that it is "expecting a declaration." I have been searching through notes and messing with this all day and I cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. I am using MS Visual studio Express 2013.

Comment: If the function body is right underneath the declaration of `PrintIntro`, you don't need a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

Adding the semicolon after `void PrintIntro()` tells the compiler that there is a function called `PrintIntro` that takes no arguments and returns void, and that you are defining it later. This is called a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration). Chances are this is what's happening:

```
void PrintIntro();
//Compiler: okay, that was a forward declaration

{
    //Compiler: wth is this stuff?
}
```

You want *this* to happen:

```
void PrintIntro();
//Compiler: okay, that was a forward declaration

void PrintIntro()
{
    //Compiler: oh, this is the definition for that function you told me about earlier
}
```

Or you want to do it without the forward declaration:

```
void PrintIntro()    //no ';'
{
    //Compiler: declaration and function body all in one part - simple!
}
```

You should also change `#include iostream` to `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate those explanations and they do help and make sense as I read them.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ; after you declare you function like:

```
void PrintIntro()
```

When declaring a function, you do not need to end the function declaration line with a semicolon.

So your function should look like

```
void PrintIntro(){
    blahblahblah...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it, that has fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the semi column at the end of the declaration

```
void PrintIntro();
```

Must be like this

```
void PrintIntro(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of errors, most of them in the syntax I think. Note that the line `#include iostream` should actually be `#include <iostream>` and the `;` is missing after `void PrintIntro()`.

Like so

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void PrintIntro(){
  cout << "Hello world" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the time taken to help me out.